# Knp Snappy Bundle Options

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using [KnpSnappyBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle) for my Symfony project and I'm trying to define some options in my config file. However if I set, for example:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    [ 'no-outline' ]
```

I get an error:
`The option '0' does not exist.`

How do I define options for the bundle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, that was kinda dumb of me. YAML to the answer:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:
            no-outline: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled: true
        binary: /path/to/wkhtmltopdf
        options:
            - { name: 'page-size', value: 'A4' }
```

Comment: This is very similar to the accepted answer, could you add a short description to explain the difference? Thank you!